# Error after connecting IBOutlet to UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield, iboutlet

I'm getting this weird error when I connect an IBOutlet to a UITextField. It's really weird because it's only happening in this one view controller. I have two other view controllers almost identical to this one, and they function perfectly. I have a table view controller in my storyboard. It has 2 grouped sections, each with static cells. Each cell has a UITextField in it. Now, the view loads fine if I just run it without connecting the textfields to my class. However, when I do connect them, as soon as the view loads-the app crashes with this error, one for each textfield: [UITextField stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Any idea what the cause of this could be? I'm very confused as I have other tableview controllers with the same contents and I've never gotten this error.

Here are some screenshots to help further explain my situation:

[image: wiring diagram from Xcode]

[image: list of properties in a header file]

Here is the code for my .m file:

```
    //
//  IdeaViewController.m
//  FinalJSApp
//
//  Created by Jacob Klapper on 10/20/13.
//
//

#import "IdeaViewController.h"

@interface IdeaViewController ()

@end

@implementation IdeaViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

Comment: Well, `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` is a method of `NSString` so that error is correct. Are you using that method in your code? Can you show the code?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using that method, which is why this is weird. I just tried to do this from scratch again. I deleted the class, as well as the view on the storyboard. Here is what I found out: This happens after I add the connection to the second textfield. One textfield with an IBOutlet connection works fine, but as soon as I add the second textfield/outlet, the app crashes. So weird....

My only code is the IBOutlet in the .h file of my class: (Only pasted one):

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *type;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You declare two properties, `title` and `description`, in your view controller that are **already defined** by `UIViewControlller` and `NSObject` respectively.  Both of those properties as originally defined are `NSString`s.

iOS is probably trying to access those properties, expecting an `NSString`, and getting one of your `UITextField`s.

Try renaming those properties and your problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

You are somehow sending `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`: to a `UITextField`. But `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` is an instance method of `NSString` and since `UITextField` does not implement `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` it gives you the error unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: I'm not calling this method though. The app crashes when I add an IBOutlet to the second textfield. I don't have any methods, really. Except for the defaults when I created the class..

Comment: can you post your relevant properties code to the question above?

Comment: Sure, here is the code in the .h file for my tableview controller:

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *type
;@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *title;

Comment: ok your property code seems fine. tried to reconstruct your situation with a demo project and for me it is working fine. without more knowledge about your code and setup we can't help you more. Therefore I would suggest, that you amend your question above with the full code for .m and .h of the view controller and some srceenshots of the connection inspectors for your textfield in IB.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I'll do that now. It just seems weird to me, because this is the 3rd view of my app that has almost identical contents, and this one is just crashing :(